Windows 11 Stop code SYSTEM LICENSE VIOLATION Blue Screen Error
I went to boot up my PC today and get stuck in the BSOD LOOP. PC restarts, attempts auto repair which fails, reboots loads into startup repair, loaded advanced options, attempted startup repair, "diagnosing your PC" screen runs, "checking disk for errors" screen runs, "Attempting repairs" screen runs, PC restarts, attempts to load windows and gets the "system License Violation BSOD again, process repeats

Lots of google results for that error and many possible avenues of troubleshooting. Which ones have you tried already and the result?

I have attempted the following solutions Method 1: Use the Startup Repair. : Fails
Method 2: Run SFC and DISM Scans. : runs and completes after restart BSOD is still there.
Method 3: Uninstall Recently Installed Applications uninstalled, restarted PC BSOD still there
Method 4: Run CHKDSK. : No change

This isn't forum, comments are for requesting information or clarification. Any relevant info shouldn't be provided only in comments but [edit]ed into the question. BTW, all your answers here have been reported. ChatGPT or similar aren't allowed.
